# Shemiras Einayim problem

Tags: shabbat, evil-inclination, shemirat-eynayim

Someone who's family sometimes has a certain modest young couple over their house on Shabbos for a meal.His *Yetzer Harah* can get him excited because the wife is a pretty girl. Would anyone have any good advice for someone in this situation ? Should he just not look at her?

Comment: See Mishne Torah Issurey Biah at the end of Perek 22:
 ואמרו חכמים גזל ועריות, נפשו של אדם מתאווה להן ומחמדתן  ואין אתה מוצא קהל בכל זמן וזמן, שאין בהן פרוצין בעריות ובביאות אסורות  ואמרו חכמים, רוב בגזל ומיעוט בעריות והכול באבק לשון הרע

יט  [כא] וכן ינהוג להתרחק מן השחוק, ומן השכרות, ומדברי עגבים--שאלו גורמין גדולים הם, והם מעלות של עריות; ולא יישב בלא אישה, שמנהג זה גורם לטהרה גדולה.  יתרה מכל זאת אמרו, יפנה עצמו ומחשבתו לדברי תורה, וירחיב דעתו בחכמה--שאין מחשבת עריות מתגברת, אלא בלב פנוי מן החכמה, ובחכמה הוא אומר "איילת אהבים, ויעלת חן:  דדיה, ירווך בכל עת; באהבתה, תשגה תמיד" (משלי ה,יט).